# Cramorant damage multiplier question

Tags: pokemon

I am new to Pokemon TCG. My kid and I are falling in love with it, but I get confused about some things.

Cramorant has an attack that says:
Continious Gulp Missile 60×, you can discard Arrokuda from your bench and it does 60 damage for each Arrokuda discarded this way.

My question is, what if I have no Arrokuda on my bench, does it do 60 damage or 0 damage?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[This card](https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-tcg/pokemon-cards/ss-series/swsh4/40/) for reference (VIV040).

When a card has an ‘x’, then it means times the number - which includes zero (so 60x0=0).  There is also ‘+’ which works like addition - Palkia VStar does 60+20x(number of Pokémon on both benches), so 60+0=60 if both benches are empty.

Also note that a Pokémon that does zero damage cannot have damage added to it by other modifiers (choice belt for example). The attack must do some damage before external modifiers come in.

Comment: So, Unless I have Arrokuda on my bemce it does zero damage?

Comment: Correct, zero damage. There are a lot of Pokémon attacks that work that way - multiplying by some thing you have to discard or count.